# Wiring up a shift light to a relay

Tags: electrical, car

Hi I'll try explain what I want to do 
I want my after market rev counter with shift light to switch a relay for vtec 
The problem I have is the voltage is to low to switch relay and I'm scared burning it out 
So thinking a solid state relay with very low switch what can handle 12to 14v load but can't get my head around it any help grate full on spec I need

Comment: What is the voltage?  Are you wanting to replace the light with a relay?  What wattage light is it?

Comment: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/solid-state-relay.html

Comment: Is there a shift light output on the tach? Or are you trying to connect this internally? What load are you trying to switch? VTEC solenoids?

Comment: yes the shift light is wired to a tach was going to splice the wires

Comment: it reads 12v but the live is live all the time switch is on - side and not power full enough to switch the relay

Comment: the light  reads 12v but will be very low current

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/12V-5-Black-Grey-Gasoline-RPM-Tachometer-Gauge-Rev-Counter-Shift-Light/172540792395?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D60c27a89d9664972b675c1e6e0b59a47%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D15%26mehot%3Dag%26sd%3D153351083501%26itm%3D172540792395%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Ad7c2aee3-49e5-11ea-afd1-74dbd1801c75%7Cparentrq%3A2146265a1700a9cd213ff2fdffe64a66%7Ciid%3A1

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the light with a relay? yes if posable